# Problems mocking nested classes in DNSResolver

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I have the following code:

```
import unittest, mock

class MockedRRData(object):
        def to_text(self):
            return '0 example.com.'


class MockedResponse(object):
    answer = [[MockedRRData()]]


class MockedReturnValue(object):
    response = MockedResponse()


class MockedDNSResolver(object):

    def query(self, domain_name, query_type):
        return MockedReturnValue()


class DNSQueryTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
#        MockedRRData = mock.Mock(to_text=lambda: '0 example.com.')
#        MockedResponse = mock.Mock(answer=[[MockedRRData()]])
#        MockedReturnValue = mock.Mock()
#        MockedReturnValue.attach_mock(MockedResponse, 'response')
#        MockedReturnValue = mock.Mock(response=MockedResponse())
        self.fake_dns_resolver = mock.Mock(query=lambda *args, **kwargs: MockedReturnValue())

    def test_mock(self):
        for rrset in self.fake_dns_resolver.query('a', 'b').response.answer:
            for rrdata in rrset:
                print(rrdata.to_text())

unittest.main()
```

It works, but I'd like to transition to fully using mock classes - as shown in the comments. The problem is that when I uncomment even just the last line of my comments, I get the following:

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_mock (__main__.DNSQueryTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/a.py", line 33, in test_mock
    for rrset in self.fake_dns_resolver.query('a', 'b').response.answer:
TypeError: 'Mock' object is not iterable

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I made the mistake of trying to instantiate mocks twice by adding extra `()` (mock.Mock returns an instance, not a class template). Here's the working code - compare the previously commented part.

```
import unittest, mock

class MockedRRData(object):
        def to_text(self):
            return '0 profound.mail.pairserver.com.'


class MockedResponse(object):
    answer = [[MockedRRData()]]


class MockedReturnValue(object):
    response = MockedResponse()


class MockedDNSResolver(object):

    def query(self, domain_name, query_type):
        return MockedReturnValue()


class DNSQueryTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        MockedRRData = mock.Mock(to_text=lambda: '0 profound.mail.pairserver.com.')
        MockedResponse = mock.Mock(answer=[[MockedRRData]])
        MockedReturnValue = mock.Mock(response=MockedResponse)
        self.fake_dns_resolver = mock.Mock(query=lambda *args, **kwargs: MockedReturnValue)

    def test_mock(self):
        for rrset in self.fake_dns_resolver.query('a', 'b').response.answer:
            for rrdata in rrset:
                print(rrdata.to_text())

unittest.main()
```